# Detecting which version of vswprintf() exists in Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-c++, tchar, printf

I have a project which uses `_vscwprintf()`/`vswprintf()` (via `_vsctprintf()`/`_vstprintf()`) to create formatted strings of arbitrary length in `malloc()`ed buffers.

When I started the project under Visual C++ 2008, `_vstprintf()` took three parameters:

```
int vswprintf(wchar_t * _String, const wchar_t * _Format, va_list _Ap)
```

But after leaving my project for some time when I came back to it with Visual C++ 2012, I've found that MS has changed the function to take four parameters:

```
int vswprintf(wchar_t * _String, size_t _Count, const wchar_t * _Format, va_list _Ap)
```

I would like my code to be buildable under Visual C++ 2008, 2010, and 2012 (it's portable to Linux and Solaris too).

Is there some symbol I can check for with `#ifdef` so that I can build correctly with the 3-parameter or 4-parameter version of the function?

I assume there is a symbol that tells me which version of Visual C++ I'm compiling under, but is this the correct way to do it? For instance is there some possibility that a newer compiler could build with an older C library or runtime, or vice versa?

My code is actually using C rather than C++ if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's different? MSDN for VS2008 looks like it has 4 arguments, not 3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/28d5ce15(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes I don't totally grok the documentation, it seems to have been written without a lot of care and attention to detail. But I can assure you it's been building with 3 arguments under VS2008 for the past couple of years just fine. It seems to work under VS2010 as well but it caused errors under VS2012 and I had to change the code.

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in VS2008 - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/b385ed64-d549-4cf3-af31-85a2e8da4b6a/

Comment: (My code is available on Wikimedia Toolserver Fisheye: [indexwiki](https://fisheye.toolserver.org/browse/enwikt/indexwiki))

Comment: @roger_rowland: Yes the suggested workaround of using `_vstprintf_s()` seems to work correctly under VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roger Rowland said, Due to a bug in Visual studio 2008 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/b385ed64-d549-4cf3-af31-85a2e8da4b6a/
you should pass 3 arguments in Visual studio 2008 and 4 aguments in newer versions

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER <= 1500 //Visual Studio 2008 or ealier
// use 3 parameters version here
#else //later than Visual Studio 2008
// use 4 parameters version herse
#endif
```